# How to design a low voltage astable multivirator

Tags: boost, solar-energy, astable

I am currently trying to design a solar powered energy harvester. It requires a DC to DC boost converter to increase the output voltage and keep it regulated. I found that this can be achieved using the **IC LTC3105**. But unfortunately this IC seems to be unavailable in my locality. So I have started to look for alternatives.

One Idea that has occured to me is to use a simple boost converter as shown in the picture: [image]

However this circuit will work only if the state of the switch is continuously kept changing. This circuit employs A MOSFET. Turning it on and off can be done simply by providing a square wave from an astable multivibrator.

But the real challenge arise here. I want to operate the solar panel under indoor lighting condition under which the output voltage is around roughly **300 to 700 millivolts**. I want to be able to increase it to around **5 volts** for powering small devices. This can be done easily with **LTC3105** as mentioned earlier.

Now since my input voltage is such a low value, how do I power up the astable multivibrator for switching the MOSFET? Is there a good design for low voltage astable multivibrators? Are there any other alternate boost converter designs?

**Please note that I am not allowed to use additional voltage sources.**

Comment: Are you allowed to start it with a momentary switch, or must it be self-starting? A germanium Joule Thief might do the whole boost job from 400mV and up.

Comment: please do explain germanium joule thief

Comment: In my opinion it is virtually impossible to make a power efficient low-input voltage switching regulator using discrete components. These switcher ICs which work from 250 mV etc use **low threshold** MOSFETs which you cannot get in discrete (one transistor) form. So either you have to lower your requirements a lot or use an IC that you can get hold of. TI (Texas Instruments) also make a lot of suitable ones.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie can you please mention some part numbers please.

Comment: [Joule Thief on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_thief) but using a germanium transistor, rather than a silicon type, as a silicon won't start below 700mV.

Comment: *some part numbers please* **Nope**, I'd have to search and I do not see why **I** would have to do that while you can do that yourself. You need the part, you search ! Go to the TI website and search.

Comment: To operate at 300 millivolt, you'll be operating a bipolar silicon transistor in the nanoAmp region.

Comment: @Neil_UK The joule thief efficiency is terrible. I can't imagine using that topology (or even an improved version that adds a few components) as an "energy harvester." What it does is operate at really low battery voltages (down to \$700-800\:\textrm{mV}\$) and it's really easy for any hobbyist to make and still have work, regardless of skills. It doesn't have much else going for it. Germanium won't make it more efficient. But it might make it operate, I suppose. Still. Not my choice.

Comment: @SoumyaSambeetMohapatra Look at the YX8018 and similar. The parts should abound in your area, too. Also, Texas Instruments has practically specialized in energy harvester ICs and specialized energy storage devices (cross breed between a battery and a capacitor.) You might check out their web site.